With Flutter, error while build the gradle SdkVersion
I'm making a flutter app for android I'm in the phase of deployment and as trying to resolve some problem I'm facing a lot of compatibility issues. Here is the hardest i need to build the gradle with ./gradlew clean build. The clean pass but not the build and after hours of trying without success you're my last hope.
Here is the complete error:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':device_info:checkDebugUnitTestAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > 2 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

       1.  Dependency 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
           Android APIs.

           :device_info is currently compiled against android-29.

           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
           of at least 31, for example 33.

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).

       2.  Dependency 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
           Android APIs.

           :device_info is currently compiled against android-29.

           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
           of at least 31, for example 33.

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).

Here is the current app/build.gradle (i already try the 31 and 33 version and even force the dependance as you can see
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04' }}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.s3nsa_app"
    compileSdk = 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.s3nsa_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = 21 
        targetSdk = 31
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}




Thanks for your help !

Can you try to set compileSdk and targetSdk to 34?

Is "flutter build apk" working?
What is the error when you are setting compile and target versions to above 31?

Change below line in your code, note targetSdk value.
NOTE: Remove example keyword dorm bundle is it's not accepted while publishing apk on playstore.
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.s3nsa_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = 21 
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }


Thanks for your answer. Sadly this doesn't change anything at my error. I also try to edit the compileSdk = 34 and even with this it's the same error.
What i dont understand it's that it ask clearly to udpate to version 33 but when you did it, nothing change and it's still asking for this version. It's like nothing change whatever I put in this file.
